# Trying to resolve eclipse dependencies in Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, eclipselink

I am trying to resolve Eclipse dependencies in Intellij, particularly the ASTParser dependencies and OSGI dependencies. I downloaded the maven library as well as eclipselink which after reading its description contains the eclipse libraries, however after I added the downloaded libraries and updating path, Intellij still states that the symbol eclipse, jdt, and osgi cannot be resolved. I have tried linking directories as well as individual jar files as well.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Do you use maven?

If you do mvn install .. your project compiles?

Comment: There is also [EclipseLink (non OSGi)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink) or is OSGi required?